# Math expressions in $scope.$eval()

Tags: angularjs

I was trying to execute Math operations like **sqrt**, **pow** using Math class in `$scope.$eval()`, but didn't work and always getting undefined.

**code:**

```
$scope.$eval("Math.sqrt(34)")
```

Comment: ...why are you doing this?

Comment: Guys please be patient with new users, flag the questions but do not rate it.

Comment: i have a variable which after computations turns into expression, one of such example is "43+48-Math.sqrt(8)".

Comment: That's not what $eval is for. $eval is used to evaluate Angular expressions, on the scope. Math.sqrt(34) is not an angular expression.

Comment: AngularJS expressions are evaluated against a scope object. `Math` is on the global window.  If you want to run more complex JavaScript code, you should make it a controller method and call the method . For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression).

Comment: This *feels like* an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/297619).  it's not exactly clear what you are trying to accomplish, but `$scope.$eval` won't work for what you are asking about, and using the JavaScript `eval` is generally not recommended.  It may be helpful if you describe a bit more about why you feel like you need to evaluate data as functions in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

> This sample to how use **$eval** in your controller, also you can improve your functions to get what you want.

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("ctrl", function($scope){
    $scope.sqrt = function(number){
      return Math.sqrt(number)
    };
    
    var sqrt = $scope.$eval('sqrt');
    $scope.result = sqrt(34);
    console.log(sqrt(34));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  {{result}}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks ! Looking for the same. I thought that Math.sqrt and other methods comes in angular expression.